# and [object HTMLInputElement] javascript

Tags: javascript, object

This code written as it is in a simple page generates an [object] as I needed.

```
function jsFunction(){
 var arr=document.all("camp");
 alert(arr);
}
```

HTML:

```
<input name="ctl00$MainContent$_basicDataControl$_winProbabilityPopUpControl$_winProbabilityControl$_groupWinProbabilityQuestions$ctl00$_groupPercentage" type="text" id="camp" class="readonly2" readonly="readonly"/>
<input name="ctl00$MainContent$_basicDataControl$_winProbabilityPopUpControl$_winProbabilityControl$_groupWinProbabilityQuestions$ctl01$_groupPercentage" type="text" id="camp" class="readonly2" readonly="readonly"/>
<input type="button" value="apasa aici!" onClick="jsFunction()">
```

In another page this code written with others inputs and included in a form returns an `[object HTMLInputElement]` and I can't parse the array. What could be the problem?

Comment: you cannot define an id twice or more in the same page

Comment: i tried also name="camp" instead of id="camp" and I got the same problem. I got object in the simple page and object HTMLInputElement in the main page.

Comment: How are you getting IDs like that? If these controls are rendering named like that Your IDs should be crazy long...or are you on .Net 4 and overriding the ID generation?

Comment: the names are generated in .Net4

Comment: When you set control IDs to render explicitly it's then *your* responsibility to make sure they're unique.  You likely want to reset the ID tree on the parent instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as specified in my comment above, an id must be unique in page.
so you should retrieve a collection of input instead (e.g. `document.getElementsByTagName('input')` and exclude last element (is the submit))

or in jQuery `$('input[type=text]')`

obviously you need to call that function after the elements are created